# Calculate datediff based on the week of date instead of day of date

Tags: tableau-api

Currently my data looks like this -
[image]

I have 3 sets of comparisons - Daily, Weekly, and Monthly. When comparing weekly cohorts against other weekly cohorts and monthly cohorts against other monthly cohorts, you often run into the case where the cohort is not fully 'baked'. This means, for example, the first cohort day in each week (i.e. install_cohort == 2/21/2016 with Install Cohort Week == Feb 21th) has more days_since_install than install_cohort == 2/27/2016 (the last day in the week of Install Cohort Week == Feb 21th).

When making comparisons between weeks this means not everyone has moved through the same days_since_install.

The goal is to filter the data such that every cohort has the same days_since_install which would get rid of the additional days_since_install that  install_cohort == 2/21/2016 has over install_cohort == 2/27/2016 for example. I only want to make comparisons where each week's collection of install_cohorts has the same number of days_since_install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a long discussion,

1. Create a calculated field with `{fixed [install_cohort_month]: max([install_cohort])}` and call it `[max_date]`
2. create a calculated field `datediff('day', [max_date],today())`

That gives you a table similar to this

`Month     | week      | install_cohort | max_date  | days_since_install |`

`28/2/2016 | 7/2/2016  | 1/2/2016       | 28/2/2016 | 50                 |`

`28/2/2016 | 28/2/2016 | 28/2/2016      | 28/2/2016 | 50                 |`

You can change the first calc to use the month field instead of the week field as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I feel like this is on the right track, but not quite. [Image Explination Here](http://imgur.com/TPC4UEP). For this to have worked the x axis should have been cut off - not intended.

Comment: @PhillipBlack I am not quite sure I understand what the problem is here or what you expect Tableau to display. Could you extend your question with the picture and a description on what you expect? It is also really helpful if you take a screenshot of the whole Tableau window, that we can see which dimensions and measures you use where, sometimes it's as simple as moving one pill to another shelf.

Comment: I apologize - this one is a bit tricky. 

If I'm comparing March and February, some people have more days_since_install than others. For example the people who downloaded on Feb 1st have had 77 days_since_install while people who downloaded on Feb 31st have had 49 days_since_install. This means the cohort is not fully 'baked' on day 50 for instance because the Feb 31st cohort hasn't had a chance to make it there yet. 

I want to filter such that every data point is 'fully baked' in that every cohort within that month has had the same days_since_install.

Comment: So in your example you would expect to have Feb 1st and Feb 31st to have 77 days_since_install? and to you calculate the days since install up to today? Because I assumed it to be the difference between the cohort and payment date.

Comment: No, only Feb 31st would. My goal is for the cutoff to be the days_since_install of the MAX cohorted day within the group. This would be Feb 31st for the month of February and would cutoff at days_since_install at 49. This would change dynamically if I added another month to compare.

Comment: I am still not sure I get what you try to do. But if you want the `max(date)` of a group, you can do it with a LOD calc like so: `{fixed [install_cohort_week]: max([install_cohort])}` This will give you the latest date within all records that have the same date in `[install_cohort_week]`

Comment: Bob downloaded the app on Feb 1st. Sally downloaded the app on Feb 29th. Today is April 18th, so Bob has 78 days_since_install. Sally only has 50 days_since_install. 

That means they only have 50 days_since_install in common. My chart shows as far as Bob, but I only want to show it as far as Sally.

Comment: based on that description I changed my answer. It is basically just using the two formulas I used before combined. Hope that helps

Comment: The only thing I added to top this off was a filter `IF [days_since_install] >= [cutoff - month] THEN 'Hide'
ELSE 'Show'
END`

Thank you so much for your help.